# What's the best design for extra data on behaviour class?

Tags: php, design-patterns, orm

I have a game where the player can finish some tasks.

I have separated the behaviour part of the task to its ORM part.
Eventually a copy of the task is being saved somewhere on the player's document (doesn't matter where for this specific question).

The problem is, I am not sure where to put the extra information that I send to the client that is not necessary for the behaviour itself, but it is needed to show the player information regarding the task itself.

This is my task interface:

```
interface ITask
{
    /**
     * @param Player $player
     */
    public function init(Player $player);

    /**
     * @param PlayerAction $action
     */
    public function progress(PlayerAction $action);

    public function reset();

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isComplete();
}
```

This is my abstract task:

```
abstract class BaseTask implements ITask
{
    /**
     * @var int
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $currentValue;

    /**
     * @var int
     */
    protected $targetValue;

    public function __construct($targetValue)
    {
        $this->currentValue = 0;
        $this->targetValue = $targetValue;
    }

    /**
     * @param int
     */
    public abstract function setCurrentValue($current);

    /**
     * @return  int
     */
    public abstract function getCurrentValue();

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public abstract function getID();

    /**
     * @param int
     */
    public abstract function setID($id);

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public abstract function getTargetValue();

    /**
     * @param int
     */
    public abstract function setTargetValue($target);

    /**
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isComplete()
    {
        if ($this->getCurrentValue() >= $this->getTargetValue())
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now I need to decide how where to put the extra data, e.g **description, title, theme** etc...

1. I thought about two options: I can just put it on the base task
   itself, but then what happens if I don't need it? I just leave it
   blank? feel like the wrong place for me.
2. I could create a wrapper
   class that will hold the task, but then I will need to always
   call the wrapper to get to the task, and it feels kind of
   wrong.

Looking for alternative suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inherit the CustomTask from TaskBase.

If you you have limitation in inheritance, encapsulate additional fields into a class called TaskAdditionalInfoBase and associate to the TaskBase.

Then various classes can inherit TaskAdditionalInfoBase to present a custom additional info to the the task.

Comment: But what would you do when you want to just use the task as is, without having those Additional information? Leaving them blank is kind of bad design is it now?

Comment: Another issue I have with extending is, what if I inherit from CustomTask but then I want the same behaviour of the class which extended from CustomTask on CustomTask2... It will force me to duplicate behaviour.

Comment: The main idea is to separate what you expect to change/replaced form what  you expect remain unchanged and make a contract for the changing component to be used by the general part.

Comment: I see what you mean. 
So basically I can have a NullTaskAdditionalInfo
And therefore I will not have to "waste" space.
Thanks for the idea. I'm gonna try implement it.

Comment: Of course you can let the association to be null when you don't have any extra data or behavior.